# Android LiveData<PagedList<T>>: How to merge two data sources of similar objects

Tags: android-room, android-lifecycle, android-livedata, android-paging, mediatorlivedata

I have a super class called Transaction {} and have two other classes that extend it called

InTransaction and OutTransaction.

InTransaction links to another Room entity called Source and OutTransaction links to another entity called Category.

I am able to individually observe each type's model, which returns `PagedList<? extends Transaction>`.

In my PagedListAdapter, I'd like to show both types of items. But my implementation of MediatorLiveData does not seem to work correctly. It seems the recent type replaces the old type and as a result, only one type of transaction is displayed.

I'd like to be able to see all types of transactions. Below is my current code.

```java
transactionLiveData = new MediatorLiveData<>();
transactionLiveData.addSource(inTransactionViewModel.getItems(), transactionLiveData::setValue);
transactionLiveData.addSource(outTransactionViewModel.getItems(), transactionLiveData::setValue);
transactionLiveData.observe(requireActivity(), transactionAdapter::submitList);
```

I do understand that MediatorLiveData does not do the merging for you rather simply notifies you of changes.

How can I merge the two `PagedList` into one then submit to the list?

I'm thinking of doing something like this but not sure how to instantiate the aggregator `PagedList`

```java
class TransactionMerger extends MediatorLiveData<PagedList<? extends Transaction>> {
        PagedList<? extends Transaction> inTransactions;
        PagedList<? extends Transaction> outTransactions;
        PagedList<? extends Transaction> aggregator;

        TransactionMerger(){            
        }

        @Override
        public void observe(@NonNull LifecycleOwner owner, @NonNull Observer<? super PagedList<? extends Transaction>> observer) {
            super.observe(owner, observer);
        }

        @Override
        public void setValue(PagedList<? extends Transaction> value) {
            if (isInTransactionList(value)) {
                inTransactions = value;
            }else{
                outTransactions = value;
            }
            // TODO Merge the two
            aggregator = mergeLists(inTransactions, outTransactions);
            super.setValue(aggregator );
        }

        private boolean isInTransactionList(PagedList<? extends Transaction> list) {
            return list != null && list.size() > 0 && list.get(0).getTransactionType() == Transaction.TransactionType.In;
        }
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: I don't think it's possible to merge PagedLists. You're probably going to have a better chance at merging RecyclerView.Adapters using the new `MergeAdapter`.

Comment: MergeAdapter looks really awesome. It's working ok so far. However, is it possible to order all the items by a specific field (In this case, Date timestamp, newest first). This means mixing all the items, and not just showing Adapter items first